# Classic ASP get number after equals in a string

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am fairly new to classic ASP and I have run into a bit of a problem. Hopefully there is a solution to this.

Basically I need to move a site from classic ASP to PHP. Need to extract all the internal links out of the body content for each page so that I can rewrite them as a different URL. I would do this manually but there over 200 pages and each page has about 10 links, if not more.

The current href looks like this - default.asp?contentID=123

The 123 is the page number. They range from 1 to 288

What I am trying to do is a search through the content body string find those links then replace them with a URL friendly link which will be the page name ie domain.co.uk/page-name. I can find just default.asp?conentID= easily as it is the same for all links, the issue is getting the ID number next to it so I know what to rewrite it to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Clarify how it works a bit; is it that your default.asp queries a database or picks up content in some fashion based on the contentID number? Or do you have 200 individual asps floating around out there that you need to rename? Probably a couple of page/code snippets would help, but let me clarify my ownself:

Is this the flow? default.asp picks up the querystring and renders the content based on some source that it pulls in?
Or is it that default.asp uses the querystring to route the user to one of 288 pages? Or something else entirely?

Comment: default.asp main page. It then uses the contentID to get the body content from the database and then shows it on the front end. So each default.asp?contentID= is a page

Comment: So, all of the body content is in the database? Don't you then simply need to update the data there?

Comment: Maybe if you add the code for how you get default.asp?conentID= in your file(s) we can help you add the extra code to get the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`InternetExplorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object and a `For Each` loop:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For i = 1 To 288
  ie.Navigate "http://www.example.com/default.asp?contentID=" & i
  While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
  For Each anchor In ie.document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")
    WScript.Echo anchor.href
  Next
Next

ie.Quit
```